# Не получается создать массив констант

Tags: массивы, java

Создаю интерфейс с константами и final-массивом который содержит эти константы:

```
interface SozKonstants{
    public static final String ONE="one";
    public static final String TWO="two";
    public static final String THRE="thre";
    public static final String[] NUMBER={ONE,TWO,THRE};
}
```

Но элементарное присвоение работает, компилятор не ругается мол "была попытка изменить final переменную"

```
public class SomeClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(SozKonstants.NUMBER[1]);
        SozKonstants.NUMBER[1]="ten";
        System.out.println(SozKonstants.NUMBER[1]);
    }
}
```

Не могу понять, где ошибся и как сделать так, чтобы компилятор не пропускал замену значения в массиве.

Comment: к ответам добавлю совет, - посмотрите примеры использование enumarations вполне возможно что от массива NUMBER можно будет отказатся. так как у enum'a есть метод статический метод values() который возвращает массив со всеми допустимимы константами, - что очень удобно если нужно делать итерацию для обработки всех констант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ключевое слово `final` запрещает менять значение после инициализации. Значение переменной `String[] NUMBER` - не сам массив, а ссылка на массив. Соответственно после инициализации сделать вот так:

```
SozKonstants = new String[5];
```

вы уже не сможете. На элементы массива при этом никакие ограничения на чтение-запись не накладываются, так как они не являются самостоятельными поименованными переменными.

Если вам нужен контейнер с неизменными объектами, воспользуйтесь immutable коллекциями из [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) или unmodifiable из [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/Unmodifiable.html).

---

**UPD0.** Еще можно воспользоваться тем фактом, что экземпляры перечисляемого типа являются полноценными классами. Это позволит вам сделать enum с ограниченным набором элементов, каждый из которых хранит какое-то дополнительное значение. Примерно так:

```
public enum SozKonstants {
  ONE("one"), TWO("two"), THREE("three");

  private String val;

  private SozKonstants(String value) {
    val = value;
  }

  public String getVal() {
    return val;
  }
}

public class SomeClass{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(SozKonstants.ONE.getVal());
    SozKonstants.ONE ... //ввернуть в enum значение уже не получится (если вы, конечно, не сделаете сеттер для val)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю цель в том, чтобы массив констант был `final`, коли так то можно попробовать заморочится через `enum` и сделать так:

```
interface SozKonstants
{
    public static final String ONE="One";
    public static final String TWO="Two";
    public static final String THREE="Three";
    public static enum Numbers
    {
        ONE
            {
                public String toString()
                {
                    return SozKonstants.ONE;
                }
            },
        TWO
            {
                public String toString()
                {
                    return SozKonstants.TWO;
                }
            },
        THREE
            {
                public String toString()
                {
                    return SozKonstants.THREE;
                }
            }
    }

    public static final String[] NUMBER=
    {
         Numbers.ONE.toString(), 
         Numbers.TWO.toString(), 
         Numbers.THREE.toString()
    };
}
```